# Ubuntu isn't picking up my laptop's webcam

Tags: 20.04, webcam

I'm on an older laptop that has a hp webcam-101 but I can't get Cheese or Omegle to display the Webcam's image. I'm using Ubunt 20.04.

Comment: Look at `sudo lshw --class video;ls -l /dev/video*;id`. [Edit]  your Question to reply. Don't use Add comment.

Comment: ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
uid=1000(lohroc) gid=1000(lohroc) groups=1000(lohroc),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),132(lxd),133(sambashare)